# Extract embedded resources in C#

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have four resource files embedded in my C# executable, 1 python script and 3 perl scripts. I could extract all three perl scripts successfully. But I am not able to extract the python script. I tried so many ways. Could someone please have a look ? Thank you.

```
public static string ExtractResource(string resourceName)
{
    string destFile = "";

    //look for the resource name
    foreach (string currentResource in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() )
        if (currentResource.LastIndexOf(resourceName) != -1)
        {
            string subPath = Common_Utilities.GetTempPath() + "SCRIPTS"; 
            bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);

            if (!isExists)
               System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

            string strFile = subPath + "\\" + resourceName;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFile);
            string rootName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile);
            destFile = path + @"\" + rootName + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(currentResource);

            System.IO.Stream fs = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( currentResource ) ;

            byte[] buff = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buff, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            fs.Close();

            System.IO.FileStream destStream = new System.IO.FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create);
            destStream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            destStream.Close();
    }

    return destFile;
    // throw new Exception("Resource not found : " + resourceName);
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the Python script can't be extracted.... couple points though:

1. I would recommend to use `Path.Combine()` to stick together path and file name - don't do this yourself, too many chances for error!
2. Since those are (text-based) scripts, you could do the whole copying much simpler:

   ```
    System.IO.Stream fs = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(currentResource);

    string scriptContents = new StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd();
    File.WriteAllText(destFile, scriptContents);
   ```

   With this approach, you should be easily able to see in debugging whether or not the script is properly loaded from resources. If not - check your resource name etc. (is the script really set to "embedded" resource?). If you have subdirectories for your resources, be aware that the **resource name** will contain those subdirectories as part of the fully qualified name - but separated by a dot (`.`), not a backslash like a physical path!

Comment: My problem here is, it is not getting into the if statement for that particular resource. For all other resources it goes in the if statement and works fine.

Comment: @infant_coder: so what are those four resource names that you get? Look at them, and find out why the Python script doesn't match your `IF` clause (what is that if clause supposed to do anyway???)

Comment: I modified the python script's resource name as seen in the current resource and now it is extracting properly. No code change. Thank you marc_s and all others.

Answer (score -1):

easy way you can mod your code with

```
Binary files -> File.WriteAllBytes(Path, Properties.Resources.filename);
Text files -> File.WriteAllText(Path, Properties.Resources.filename);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation and context along with your answer to help other users understand it! Thanks for contributing.