# Store and open a Workbook in VSTO as "resource"

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

So, I have a workbook which is pretty complicated to reproduce programatically. To make my work faster and easier I am looking for a solution to "store" the workbooks into my VSTO to be free to open a copy of it.
It seems useful to me but I haven't find any way to do it for now.
I hope someone can help me to do it or explain to me how to do a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of Eugene i figured a way to do.
And it allow me to help another people so to more information see my answer on :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777392/13069899

Thanks.

Comment: Actually it is for the other people to have a solution if they have the same problem so they have the solution i made.

Comment: Didn't the code posted extract a file from the resources?

Comment: It didn't worked for me, the file was an .xlsx document. But gave me the right path to find the solution, that's why i upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just include it to the VSTO add-in installer along with other files. So, the workbook will be kept with other add-in files in the installer folder. At any point of time, you can make a copy. There is no need to include it in the resources.

Anyway, in case if you need to extract the file from resources on the fly, see [Extract embedded resources in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584040/extract-embedded-resources-in-c-sharp):

```
System.IO.Stream fs = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(currentResource);

string scriptContents = new StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(destFile, scriptContents);
```

But your antivirus software may not be happy with this solution!

Comment: Thank's i'll try it tommorrow !