# How do I open a PDF included in my C# project in a browser window upon link click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pdf

I have a folder in my project called "Guides" and have added "My Admin Guide.pdf".

The relevant xaml:

```
<TextBlock Margin="20,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Hyperlink x:Name="Documentation_Hyperlink" NavigateUri="/Guides/My Admin Guide.pdf" TargetName="_blank" RequestNavigate="Documentation_Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        Click Here for the Admin Guide
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

In the code-behind:

```
private void DDI_Documentation_Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```

When I test, I get an exception "the system cannot find the file specified". I've verified e.Uri.ToString() has a value of /Guides/My Admin Guide.pdf. How do I do this properly?

Comment: You probably need to use [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start) and set [`WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory) to your executable's directory.

Comment: Use the SysInternals Process Monitor tool to see where your app is looking. I'm pretty sure @dourhigharch is right

Comment: We'd need to know how you “have added "My Admin Guide.pdf"”, how you are testing, and your deployment technology to tell you how to find your executable's directory programmatically.

Comment: I added them by placing the PDFs in the folder and then "Add Existing Item" to the project. I'm testing by clicking the hyperlink, which gives me the error that it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy as a link method to do the trick but the method once practiced is not so complicated.
First of all assure yourself the PDF document is generated as an embedded resource.
Then follow those steps :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("{your_assembly_name}.{your_folder_and_file_name}");
FileInfo source = new FileInfo("{a_name_for_the_file}");
byte[] b;

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
  b = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
}
File.WriteAllBytes(source.FullName, b);
```

This will save the file into the user's computer, on the document, but the `File` will contain the path to open it easily.
If you rather like the user don't have it on his computer you can "hide" it to a temp folder using `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` when you create the FileInfo.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had actually come up with something similar, but was copying to the users Temp directory (environment variable). Thanks!