# How can I open a PDF that is in my Resource Folder?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a folder `Resources` that has multiple Icons/PDF Files in it.
When I'm in the `.xaml` I can simply access them using `Source="/Resources/Icon.png"`.

Now I'm trying to open a PDF File via Code that is embedded in `Resources`.

I tried, but it's saying that the File was not found.

```
Process.Start("/Resources/File.pdf")
```

After some research I found this:

```
        String strAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        String strFilePath = Path.Combine(strAppPath, "Resources");
        String strFullFilename = Path.Combine(strFilePath, "File.pdf");
```

The problem here is, that it gets the path of my debug folder, which doesn't have `Resources` as a folder. So How can I open a PDF File that is in my `Resources` Folder?

Comment: try to set  copy to output directory to always

Comment: The Icon is compiled into your executable (look at the Build action: "Resource") and can be accessed from XML files there. Wih the PDF, you could change the Build action to "None" and instead select "Copy to output directory", then you will fild the PDF next to your executable. Alternatively, use Build Action "Embedded resource" and get the PDF as stream using `GetManifestResourceStream`.

Comment: As I used to have a similar issue i let you follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777392/13069899 This is the solution i use and even if it is not sexy it works fine.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path instead of `"/Resources/File.pdf"`?