# Excel COM add-in internal sheets (Add-in Express)

Tags: excel, com, vsto, add-in, addin-express

I want to convert a VBA Excel add-in (xlam file) to a COM add-in, written in C# and using Add-in Express (although this might not be relevant). The VBA add-in has several internal sheets that are used for various operations - for example a base for creating template sheets (see screenshot).
Is there any way to have this kind of sheets in a COM add-in? If not, which would be the best approach to have some template sheets?
Thank you for your time!

Adrian

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have tried asking Add-in Express guys first?

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your interest! I'm not sure if Add-in Express can help with this. Don't have a license yet (although will most probably buy one, as it will help me with a lot of other things!) and I didn't find anything related on your forums. Can't post there without a license, so...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this thread: [Store and open a Workbook in VSTO as "resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555578/store-and-open-a-workbook-in-vsto-as-resource)
The idea is to add the template workbook to the project and setup, so it gets extracted with all other add-in files. Then use the sheets from there.